# How to hide .class files in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for a Java project. After compiling the project, on the IDE's file explorer, I both `*.java` files and `*.class` files.

Is there a good reason why I might want VS Code to show me the `*.class` files as well?
How do I make VS Code show / hide the bytecode files?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved by adding `*.class` to the `files:exclude` list in preference.

Comment: "files.exclude": { 
        "**/*.class": true,
    }